# Sending parameter with function to child component and back to parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I've got a custom component called `InputWithButton` that looks like this:

```
const InputWithButton = ({ type = "text", id, label, isOptional, name, placeholder = "", value = "", showPasswordReset, error, isDisabled, buttonLabel, handleChange, handleBlur, handleClick }) => (
    <StyledInput>
        {label && <label htmlFor="id">{label}{isOptional && <span className="optional">optioneel</span>}</label>}
        <div>
            <input className={error ? 'error' : ''} type={type} id={id} name={name} value={value} placeholder={placeholder} disabled={isDisabled} onChange={handleChange} onBlur={handleBlur} autoComplete="off" autoCorrect="off" />
            <Button type="button" label={buttonLabel} isDisabled={isDisabled} handleClick={() => handleClick(value)} />
        </div>
        {error && <Error>{Parser(error)}</Error>}
    </StyledInput>
);

export default InputWithButton;
```

`Button` is another component and looks like this:

```
const Button = ({ type = "button", label, isLoading, isDisabled, style, handleClick }) => (
    <StyledButton type={type} disabled={isDisabled} style={style} onClick={handleClick}>{label}</StyledButton>
);

export default Button;
```

I'm using the InputWithButton component in a parent component like this:

```
render() {
    const { name } = this.state;
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <InputWithButton label="Name" name="Name" buttonLabel="Search" value={name} handleChange={this.handleChange} handleClick={this.searchForName} />
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

If the button is clicked, the `searchForName` function is called:

```
searchForName = value => {
    console.log(value); //Input field value
}
```

This is working but I want to add another parameter to it but this time, a parameter that comes from the parent component

```
// handleClick={() => this.searchForName('person')}

<InputWithButton label="Name" name="Name" buttonLabel="Search" value={name} handleChange={this.handleChange} handleClick={() => this.searchForName('person')} />
```

The output in `searchForName` is now 'person' instead of the value.

I thought I could fix this with the following code:

```
searchForName = type => value => {
    console.log(type); //Should be person
    console.log(value); //Should be the value of the input field
}
```

However this approach doesn't execute the function anymore.

How can I fix this?

EDIT: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YgpOGE)

Comment: this.searchForName('person')} is just calling the function searchForName with the argument of 'person' - that function is just logging this argument out. What value were you expecting?

Comment: @DaleKing I'm expecting the value that I'm passing from the parent component so 'person' and the value that I'm passing in `InputWithButton` so the 'value of the input' field.

Comment: Ah i see what you mean now. Can you throw up a code sandbox with the relevant sections?

Comment: @DaleKing I added a Codepen link. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YgpOGE

Answer (score 0):

I would try `handleClick={this.searchForName.bind(this, 'person')}`, please let me know if it'll work for you.

EDIT:
I changed fragment from your codepen, it's working:

```
searchName(key, value) {
    console.log(key);
    console.log(value);
  }

  render() {
    const { name } = this.state;

    return (
      <InputWithButton name="name" value={name} buttonLabel="Search" handleChange={this.handleChange} handleClick={this.searchName.bind(this, 'person')} />
    )
  }
```

Comment: what's the value of the this parameter when you console.log it in searchForName func? Your searchForName should be like: `searchForName(param1, param2) { //func body}`, without additional binding () =>

Comment: EDIT: by the this parameter I mean one passed from parent component, in this case console log of param2.

Comment: It's working without the additional binding and with the .bind
Can you explain your solution?

Comment: the docs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) are really helpful with this one: The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

Answer (score 0):

as I suspected, just pass it an object and make sure you're accepting the argument in your handleClick function

`handleClick={value => this.searchName({value, person: 'person'})}`

or more verbose - without the syntactic sugar

`handleClick={value => this.searchName({value: value, person: 'person'})}`

then you can get at it with value.person

full [codepen here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EMNezv?editors=0010)

Hope this helps